# CakePHP 3.x - How to filter one association by fields of another association?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0, contain

When - like in the manual - one can filter on a given variable.

```
$username = 'markstory';
$query = $articles->find()->matching('Comments.Users', function ($q) use ($username) {
    return $q->where(['username' => $username]);
});
```

How can you filter on a value from another contain value?
I thought example below would be possible. But it's not.

```
$query = $articles->find()->contain('Names')->matching('Comments.Users', function ($q) use ($username) {
    return $q->where(['username' => Names.username]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For one that would only work in case of a `hasOne` or `belongsTo` associtiation that is using the `join` strategy, otherwise the table would not be included in the main query.

`Query::contain()` and `Query::matching()` however do not play well together because they appear in a fixed order, that is `matching` joins will be placed before `contain` joins, which makes using conditions via the `Query::matching()` callback impossible. You'll either have use `Query::leftJoinWith()` or `Query::innerJoinWith()` instead, which respects the order of method calls, or add the conditions to the main query.

Your field comparison is invalid PHP, but even when quoted correctly that wouldn't work, you'd have to either pass a raw SQL snippet as a single value, or better yet built it via expressions, for example using the `QueryExpression::equalFields()` method.

```php
$query = $articles
    ->find()
    ->innerJoinWith('Names')
    ->matching('Comments.Users', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $q) use ($username) {
        return $q->where(function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp) {
            return $exp->equalFields('Users.username', 'Names.username');
        });
    });
```

```php
// only works in case `Names` is a `hasOne` or `belongsTo` association
$query = $articles
    ->find()
    ->contain('Names')
    ->matching('Comments.Users')
    ->where(function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp) {
        return $exp->equalFields('Users.username', 'Names.username');
    });
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression::equalFields()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html#_equalFields)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Query::where()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_where)**